# How to redirect to previous page with message in magento 2 frontend?

Tags: magento-2.1, validation, form-validation, global-messages

I have a form that post data to controller in Magento 2 Frontend, i want to do some validation, and redirect back to previous page after validation with success or error message, here's how i redirect back to previous page:

```
public function execute()
    {
        // Do Validation
        if(empty($input))
         $message = 'error';
        else
         $message = 'success';
        $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
    }
```

Comment: If my answer worked could you accept my answer , but if it didn't work then tell me whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show your error/success message with `ManagerInterface`.
Here is an example to show you how you can use it.

```
  <?php


    use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
    use \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class ClassName extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Do Validation
        if (empty($input)) {
            $this->_messageManager->addErrorMessage('Your Error Message');
        } else {
            $this->_messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Your Success Message');
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: can i set multiple error message?

Comment: Yes, just  call `addErrorMessage` method.

Comment: How can I return my collection from controller to the previous page?

Comment: Hi @Vinodkumar,

if you wish to get an answer then it's better to create your own question. A comment is not best way to get an answer.

Comment: I had created my own question but there is no response till now: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190971/how-to-return-collection-from-controller-to-view-page-in-magento-2