# how to return collection from controller to view page in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using the custom module. I have added the search box on the cms page and add search query in the controller. After searching the keyword data collection is generating correctly. But, now I want to send this data collection on the same search page. How can I achieve this?

I am using below code in controller:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Allin\ReorderForm\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
//protected $resultPageFactory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
class Search extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        //$this->_view->loadLayout();
        //echo 'testtttttttt'; die;
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        //$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
        if (!$post) {
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        if(1)
        {           
            $query = $post['search'];
            echo 'Query = '.$query;

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $Collection = $objectManager->create('Allin\Pharmacy\Model\Pharmacy')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('pharmacy_name', array('like' => '%'.$query.'%'));
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($Collection->getData());  die;

            foreach($Collection as $data){
                    echo $data->getPharmacyName();
            }
            die;
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(
                __('Something missing in your details!')
            );
        }

      $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect; 
    }
/*  public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        echo $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('foo', 'bar');

        return $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory')->create();
    } */
    /**
     * Get Data Persistor
     *
     * @return DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private function getDataPersistor()
    {
        if ($this->dataPersistor === null) {
            $this->dataPersistor = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(DataPersistorInterface::class);
        }

        return $this->dataPersistor;
    }
}
```